# generating resource file (Resource Generator)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to c# programming..
I'm using windows form application c#  .net
I have been given a .resources file. it contains 2 columns 1) key  and 2) values.
I have brought the contents of this file into a datagrid using dynamic table in between and using resource manager.
Now i have to edit the value column in the datagrid and if i click on a GENERATE button i should create a new resource file and it has to be stored as a file.  In the same way i should create many sucj resource file.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [ResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter.aspx) class for this.